# How can I fix a website that doesn't work on my computer?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, internet-explorer, website

Tech support for the school website says it is Internet Explorer but every other website works? I need to be able to access classes on this website. We have two other computers and they are working fine with the site. But my Toshiba laptop is not. The computer has been cleaned scanned and backed up but the site still will not work.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what doesn't work. You might need to update IE, or flash, or java, or any number of things.

Comment: what about installing another browser? I know that many people (including me) use at least two or three (Firefox probably renders the best after IE, Chrome still has some dificulty)

Comment: Has it worked before?

Answer (score 0):

Without exact information, its hard to say what's wrong. There's a few things i tend to try with web site access issues - isitdownforeveryoneorisitjustme.com is useful if its down on ALL systems in a lan, but its not the case for you.

1. try another browser - preferably a portable one if you don't want to install a new one
2. try switching the DNS server - openvpn or google dns are good. Don't forget to flush the DNS afters
3. try using a proxy - I have my own for testing, but tor works well at a pinch. If 1 didn't work operator is a nice opera respin with tor in it i've used before.